# SSRS Report Formatting

Tags: layout, reporting-services, formatting, reporting

How do I convert a report's layout aspect from linear to tabular, so as to eliminate page breaks and keep the results all on one page?  In the image, there's the existing format and a desired format.  The existing format highlights the rows on which they currently page break.  The desired format shows how the user wants to put the data in the report so it's only on one page.

Example of report format (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aavnZ.jpg)

I tried column grouping but am not sure what would make the report change to the desired format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is to use a matrix and calculate the row and column number that each current row should appear in. Without seeing your actual current report design though, it's difficult to give a better answer.